# Keep moving images bouncing within frame width and height

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to figure out how to keep an image within the frame width and height. Right now it just wraps around. I would preferably like to create something that stays within the frame and bounces around inside.

```
-(void) moveButterfly {
    bfly.center = CGPointMake(bfly.center.x + bfly_vx, bfly.center.y + bfly_vy);

    if(bfly.center.x > frameWidth)
    {
        bfly.center = CGPointMake(0, bfly.center.y + bfly_vy);
    }
    else if (bfly.center.x < 0)
    {
        bfly.center = CGPointMake(frameWidth, bfly.center.y + bfly_vy);
    }

    if(bfly.center.y > frameHeight)
    {
        bfly.center = CGPointMake(bfly.center.x + bfly_vx, 0);
    }
    else if (bfly.center.y < 0)
    {
        bfly.center = CGPointMake(bfly.center.x + bfly_vx, frameHeight);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good beginning programming logic exercise. You should put on your thinking cap and sort it out yourself. Hint: there are two parts: 1. how you are doing the movement; 2. how you are doing the bounds checking.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)moveButterfly{
    static int dx = 1;
    static int dy = 1;
    if (bfly.frame.origin.x >= self.view.bounds.size.width - bfly.bounds.size.width) {
        dx = -dx;
    }
    if (bfly.frame.origin.y >= self.view.bounds.size.height - bfly.bounds.size.height) {
        dy = -dy;
    }
    if (bfly.frame.origin.x <= 0) {
        dx = -dx;
    }
    if (bfly.frame.origin.y <= 0) {
        dy = -dy;
    }
    CGPoint point = bfly.center;
    point.x += dx;
    point.y += dy;
    bfly.center = point;
}
```

Keep Calling this function using NSTimer at the rate you want to update position. Here dx and dy is the velocity at which butterfly will move.